# How to convert a windows FILETIME to a std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::file_clock> in C++

Tags: c++, windows, c++20, c++-chrono, filetime

I'm looking for a way to convert a Windows [`FILETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/filetime) structure to a [`std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::file_clock>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_time_type) so that I can build a difference between two file times and express that duration f.e. in [`std::chrono::microseconds`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

**EDIT**: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/W7Wa4r6eP) is a complete godbolt example of [Howard's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72031262/17637875).

Comment: Reopened because the "duplicate" did not address the conversion to `std::chrono::file_clock::time_point`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer:*  I don't have a Windows system to test on.

I believe that one just needs to take the high and low words of the `FILETIME` and interpret that 64 bit integral value as the number of tenths of a microsecond since the `std::chrono::file_clock` epoch:

```
FILETIME ft = ...
file_clock::duration d{(static_cast<int64_t>(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32)
                                           | ft.dwLowDateTime};
file_clock::time_point tp{d};
```

Both the units and the epoch of `FILETIME` and `file_clock` (on Windows) are identical.

Comment: I am using C++11 and have no `std::chrono::file_clock` available yet. Just `std::chrono::system_clock`. Don't know about the first one, but for the `std::chrono::system_clock` you need to subtract 116444736000000000 after combining upper and lower `DWORD` of the `FILETIME`. Otherwise, the time_point is off.

Comment: Right.  The epoch of both `FILETIME` and `std::chrono::file_clock` is 1601-01-01 (on Windows).  And the epoch of `std::chrono::system_clock` is 1970-01-01.  Windows ticks are deci-microseconds and there are 116444736000000000 of those between these two epochs.

Comment: Do not do this. In standard chrono::file_clock epoch is unspecified. So this is not portable code. Sometimes with portable code you still need to handle FILETIME struct with legacy code.

Comment: Of course this is not portable code.  `FILETIME` is a Windows-only structure.