# std::filesystem::last_write_time to FILETIME

Tags: c++

I am attempting to send over the `FILETIME` of a file to my server, which is written in C#. From there, I can use the function `DateTime.FromFileTime()` to parse the file's time. I am aware there is a Win32 API called `GetFileTime()`, but in the interest of saving lines of code, I was wondering if it was possible to use `std::filesystem` and somehow convert it to `FILETIME`?

I have tried casting like so:

```
f.lastwrite = entry.last_write_time();
```

But this cast is not allowed, unfortunately. Is it possible to convert the `last_write_time()` to `FILETIME` so it can be sent over, or is that not possible?

Comment: If you're sending a time over the Internet, it would be better to do it in text, with a specific format and known timezone, rather than as an integer.

Comment: What is _wrong_ with using `GetFileTime`, since it gives you exactly what you want?

Comment: @PaulSanders Nothing is inherently wrong, it would just require more lines of code and I was trying to stick to using std::filesystem. If it's not possible, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `last_write_time()` value to `std::time_t` via [`std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/file_clock/to_from_sys) and [`std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t), and then [convert `time_t` to `FILETIME` using simple arithmetic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/converting-a-time-t-value-to-a-file-time).

For example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>

void stdFileTimeType_to_FILETIME(const std::filesystem::file_time_type &ftime, FILETIME &ft)
{
    std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
        std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys(ftime)
    );
    ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
    ul.QuadPart = (t * 10000000LL) + 116444736000000000LL;
    ft.dwLowDateTime = ul.LowPart;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = ul.HighPart;
}

FILETIME lastwrite;
stdFileTimeType_to_FILETIME(entry.last_write_time(), lastwrite);
```

---

**UPDATE:** Alternatively, have a look at [`GetFileAttributesEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw), which can retrieve `FILETIME ftLastWriteTime` (amongst other things) given a file path string instead of an open file `HANDLE`, as with `GetFileTime()`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>

void getLastWriteTime_as_FILETIME(const std::filesystem::path &filePath, FILETIME &ft)
{
    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fad;
    if (GetFileAttributesExW(path.c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &fad))
        ft = fad.ftLastWriteTime;
    else
        ft.dwLowDateTime = ft.dwHighDateTime = 0;
}

FILETIME lastwrite;
getLastWriteTime_as_FILETIME(entry.path(), lastwrite);
```

Comment: Doesn't that limit the precision to one second?  `GetFileTime` is a lot more precise than that, as I'm sure you both know.

Comment: @PaulSanders "*Doesn't that limit the precision to one second?*" - basically, yes. But unless you know the exact implementation of `file_time_type` and can do the necessary math yourself from `file_time_type` directly to `FILETIME`, this is about as good as you can get with standard functionality. Otherwise, like you said earlier, just use `GetFileTime()` instead, or `GetFileAttributesEx()` (which doesn't require opening the file).

Comment: Absolutely.  If it looks like Windows and quacks like Windows ... `GetFileAttributesEx()` a good idea.

Comment: On Windows I believe that `FILETIME` and `std::filesystem::file_time_type` share the same epoch and the same precision.  So just converting from serial to fields should do the job, without any loss of precision.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72031262/576911.  However I'm not clear on what epoch the client of this conversion wants to see.